# Split the using $arrayElement if its not there then NA in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation:

I am using the,

```
"A":{ "$arrayElemAt" :[ {"$split" : ["$info_id" , "_"]},0]},
"B":{ "$arrayElemAt" :[ {"$split" : ["$info_id" , "_"]},1]},
"C":{ "$arrayElemAt" :[ {"$split" : ["$info_id" , "_"]},2]},
```

but if after 2nd `_` nothing is there then I want the output to be as "NA".

Document 1:

```
  "info": {
    "id": "2_452_1",
  },
```

Document 2:

```
  "info": {
    "id": "9_5",
  },
```

Expected output Document 1:

```
{ 
  "A": "2",
  "B": "452",
  "C": "1"
}
```

Expected output Document 2:

```
{ 
  "A": "9",
  "B": "5",
  "C": "NA"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$split` to split `id` string by "_"
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from above result array from split
- `$ifNull` to check return result from the above operation is null then return "NA"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { info: { $split: ["$info.id", "_"] } } },
  {
    $project: {
      A: {
        $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$info", 0] }, "NA"]
      },
      B: {
        $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$info", 1] }, "NA"]
      },
      C: {
        $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$info", 2] }, "NA"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vCsY5XtZG1I)